# How to run .Appimage on ubuntu 17.10

Tags: github, file-permissions, ubuntu-17.10, appimage

How to run .AppImage on ubuntu 17.10?

I did cura-build from the following exec (AppRun and Appimagetool) files from https://github.com/AppImage/AppImageKit/releases

```
~cura-build/build$ make
Copying AppRun executable...
...
...
...
...
...
Embedding ELF...
Marking the AppImage as executable...
Success

Please consider submitting your AppImage to AppImageHub, the crowd-sourced
central directory of available AppImages, by opening a pull request
at https://github.com/AppImage/appimage.github.io
[ 98%] Built target packaging
Scanning dependencies of target signing
[100%] Signing Package...
Generating signature...
Generating SHA-1 sum...
[100%] Built target signing
```

After generated package I got an .Appimage file, then I try to run this file,

```
~: chmod a+x Cura-0.0.0-master.AppImage
~: ./Cura-0.0.0-master.AppImage
execv error: No such file or directory
```

I checked with these file properties as 'Allow executing file as program'

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Please download a readymade AppImage from https://ultimaker.com/en/products/ultimaker-cura-software and report issues at https://github.com/Ultimaker/Cura/issues, thanks.

Comment: I had resolved this above error and I could able to run AppImage file from cura-build.

Comment: I fixed by,..........What you need to do is building a prefix with cura-build-environment first.
This will provide all dependencies for you.
After that you have to point with cura-build on the built prefix by cura-build-environment.

Answer (score 0):

for **RUN**

in linux(ubuntu)

```
chmod +x Name.AppImage

./Name.AppImage
```